# Generate Prepared Statement Inside For Loop

Tags: java, switch-statement, prepared-statement

I have a SQL Server table which number of row and the column name generated by using loop. Now for the data insert, I need to generate Prepared Statement inside for loop based on number of rows. My first approach by using Switch Case.

```
int numberOfRows;
PreparedStatement statement;
Object[] rowObjects;


 switch (numberOfRows) {
      case 1 -> {
           statement.setString(1, String.valueOf(rowObjects[0]));
      }
      case 2 -> {
           statement.setString(1, String.valueOf(rowObjects[0]));
           statement.setString(2, String.valueOf(rowObjects[1]));
      }
      case 3 -> {
           statement.setString(1, String.valueOf(rowObjects[0]));
           statement.setString(2, String.valueOf(rowObjects[1]));
           statement.setString(3, String.valueOf(rowObjects[2]));
      }
 }

statement.executeUpdate();
```

As you can see it is highly ineffective. Is there a better way than this?

Comment: You aren't generating a `PreparedStatement` at all here, let alone inside a `for` loop.

Comment: Looks like it should be `numberOfColumns` to me…

Comment: Use an ORM mapper?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your switch/case statement could be written something like this.

```
for (int index = 0; index < numberOfRows; index++) {
    statement.setString(index + 1, String.valueOf(rowObjects[index]);
}
```